# How to add QuantLib to a virtualenv (ubuntu)

Tags: python, virtualenv, ubuntu-14.04, quantlib, quantlib-swig

I am using pydev and a virtualenv (which has already been set up successfully). How do you add quantlib (and for that matter any python wrapper plus its C++ native library) to a virtualenv?

I successfully built quantlib and the quantlib-SWIG from source as described [here](http://quantess.net/2012/09/26/quantlib-get-it-working-on-ubuntu/). I notice that after the boost build, *//usr/local/lib* contains *libQuantLib.** files which are probably the native libs.

I then tried copying *libQuantLib.** to my *virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages*, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25693640/use-c-compiled-library-in-virtualenv) but eclipse still complains about unresolved imports (at this point I am also externally referencing *//usr/local/lib/QuantLib-SWIG-1.4/Python/build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7/QuantLib* folder). I am not sure if I had this correctly working.

I have seen [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12124726/import-of-swig-python-module-fails-with-apache) solution, but I really want everything contained in the virtualenv - both the python wrapper and C++ libraries, so everything is resolved when I set the project's pydev interpreter as my virtualenv.

I am unsure what best practices are here.

Answer (score 2):

I'm not familiar with the way the virtualenv is set up. However: from the fact that your Python modules are in `virtualenv/lib/python2.7/site-packages`, I'd guess that the native libraries should go in `virtualenv/lib`. The correct way to have everything set up there, though, would be to tell the build machinery where you want the library; in your case (and assuming my guess above is correct) you'd do it by building QuantLib with:

```
./configure --prefix=/path/to/virtualenv
make
make install
```

where `/path/to/virtualenv` is the path to your virtualenv, including the `virtualenv` folder (but **not** `lib`). This will put header files and native libraries in the correct place in the virtualenv. After this, build QuantLib-SWIG using the QuantLib libraries you just installed: I think the easiest way is to do it from within the virtualenv (that is, using the Python interpreter inside it). Activate the env, enter the QuantLib-SWIG/Python directory, and run:

```
export PATH=/path/to/virtualenv/bin:$PATH
python setup.py build
python setup.py install
```

where setting `PATH` as above might be needed to find the correct `quantlib-config` script. (By the way, you should end up with just a `QuantLib` Python module in `site-packages`, not the whole `build/lib.linux-x86_64-2.7` thing you have now.)